# JavaScript search for object in an object and return both's elements

Tags: javascript, object, search

I've got an object like this:

```
{
    "Peter": {
        "data": {
            "id": 104,
            "budget": 3400
        },
        "items": {
            "shoes": {
                "sales": 72,
                "intake": 576
            },
            "books": {
                "sales": 14,
                "intake": 70
            } 
        }
    },
    "Bradley": {...}
}
```

The `Peter` object repeats several times with other names.

Now I want to search for lets say `books`.

If `books` is found somewhere in the object, it should return the elements in the found object `books` together with it's values.

I also want to know in which grandobject `books` was found. So in this case it should return `Peter`.

If `books` was found in several objects, it should return the results in an array.

I know how to get an object by searching for one of its properties by using the `find()` method, but I'm wondering how you do it when the objects you're searching through have names you don't know before.

Comment: right, what have you tried?

Comment: I tried the `find()` method but I don't know how to layout the whole thing to make it work as I described.

Comment: please add, what ever you might have tried, to the question. please add whyt does not work, too.

Comment: @CodingBobby Please update your question and include your attempt(s). Without showing them your question appears to be asking for someone to write for you.

Answer (score 0):

[`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), and [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) can be combined to construct an `array` consisting only of `people` with `predicated` `items`.

See below for a practical example.

```js
// Input.
const people = {"Peter": {"data": {"id": 104, "budget": 3400}, "items": {"shoes": {"sales": 72, "intake": 576}, "books": {"sales": 14, "intake": 70 }}}}

// People With.
const peopleWith = (o, ...p) => Object.entries(o).filter(([person, attributes]) => p.every(x => Object.values(attributes.items[x] || {}).length))

// Output.
const positive = peopleWith(people, 'books')
console.log('Found', positive) // [[person, attributes] ...]
const compound = peopleWith(people, 'books', 'shoes')
console.log('Compound', compound) // People with books and shoes.
const negative = peopleWith(people, 'books', 'shoes', 'hats')
console.log('None Found', negative) // []
```

Comment: I didn't know the `entries()` method before but that helps me to understand how it works.

Comment: @CodingBobby refer this  [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). it will help you to understand the `Object.entries()`